# Artifactory Upgrade from 4 to 6 - SHA256 re-indexing takes very long

Tags: upgrade, artifactory, sha256, reindex

I am upgrading Artifactory Pro from 4.12.2 to 6.5.2. On my test instance, with around 12k artifacts, the re-indexing of the database after the upgrade takes around 12 hours. I'm afraid in my prod instance it will take close to a month (around 800k artifacts). 
- Has anyone seen this before? I did not find any articles that would indicate such a long time
- Is there a way to tune parameters to speed up the indexing?
- Is there a way to predict how much time my prod indexing would take? If it is based on number/size/type of artifacts?

Specifications:
Artifactory in HA mode installed on linux server. DB MSSQL 2016. Filestore - NAS shared mount between the HA nodes. Upgrading from 4.12.2 to 6.5.2.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, as you state you have Artifactory with HA, leads me to that you have an Enterprise subscription. Please note that Enterprise subscription allows you to contact the JFrog Support-Team at [support@jfrog.com](http://support@jfrog.com).

Now with regards to your scenario and questions, please note that JFrog mentions in their [wiki page regarding SHA-2 migration](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Checksum-Based+Storage#Checksum-BasedStorage-MigratingtheDatabasetoIncludeSHA-256), that the process is "resource intensive operation".

As you mentioned, the process can indeed take weeks/months for big filestores, but it can be tweaked by using the system properties mentioned on the same wiki page.

If you do decide to tweak it and add more workers for example, I highly recommend you to keep monitoring your database, as if the SHA2 migration will cause an impact on the database performance, your production can be affected.

As for statistics, there is no way to predict the time this process can take as it depends on the workers you specified for the job, the resources the instance has, etc..

I hope this clarifies further.